# Autolayout Resize UIView Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am attempting to get a UIView courseView to autolayout. I would like to have the proportions of the UIView remain and fill up until the outermost edges are 15 point from the edge of the superview.
For some reason courseView fills the entire superview (minus the 15 points) and does not resize to fit. So some of it does not show and is cut off.

```
    self.view.addSubview(courseView!)

    let aspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: courseView,
        attribute: .Height,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: courseView,
        attribute: .Width,
        multiplier: courseView.frame.size.height / courseView.frame.size.width,
        constant: 0.0)
    aspectConstraint.active = true

    let topConstraint = courseView.topAnchor.constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 15)
    topConstraint.active = true
    let leadingConstraint = courseView.leadingAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15)
    leadingConstraint.active = true
    let trailingConstraint = courseView.trailingAnchor.constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15)
    trailingConstraint.active = true
    let bottomConstraint = courseView.bottomAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor, constant: -15)
    bottomConstraint.active = true
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just disable translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints before adding the constraints and it should work just fine.

```
courseView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

And by the way, you do not need the aspectConstraint because that will most probably break the constratints (it did for me, when I tried).